# sfDoctrineGuard question

Tags: doctrine, forgot-password, sfguard

I'm trying to do a "i forgot my password" functionality. My problem is that if i try to do a Doctrine query and send password to email it retrieves password encrypted. I look at some webs that DoctrineGuard don't have this functionality and only have register and login functionality.

Is it true?

In this case, how i can do a remember password function?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password are hashed and then save to the database, thus you can't recover the password once it has been saved.

There are several ways you can create a "password lost" function :

- Send a new password by email (not really secure but some people like it anyway)
- Send the user an email with a reset password link (and a unique token), which either gives the user a new password, or allow the user to enter a new password.

Comment: Where you say that first method is not secure?

In second method you say... set a random password, send it in a link like.... user/reset/xdErDerfEFe  where "xdErDerfEFe" is token and in that action do a select where password = that... and allow change after?

Comment: The first method is less secure because if for example someone has access to the user inbox he can see his new password whereas with the second method, the token is only used once and then is useless after the password have been changed.

Comment: I try to do something like...

1)Put password and if username is registered do a random password and do setpassword.
2) It send a email like... 'username/password/xxxx' where xxx is generanted password
3) If you click then try to find a username with this password.


My problem is that password is encrypted and i can't find how is real encripted password :(

Do you understand me?

Answer (score 3):

From version 5.0.0 the great sfDoctrineGuard-Plugin has a built-in forgot-password module. But in the corresponding readme there is sparse info how to use it :))

```
[TODO: document the forgot password feature]
```

To use the forgot-password feature do the following (assuming you already installed the plugin and normal signin is working):

1. **enable the module** in `settings.yml` (and enable i18n as it's using it):

   ```
   all:
     .setting:
     enabled_modules: [default, sfGuardAuth, sfGuardForgotPassword]
     i18n: true
   ```
2. **add routes** in routing.yml (the automatic adding didn't work for me). And make sure you include a rule @homepage which is used for redirecting.

   ```
   sf_guard_forgot_password_change:
     url:   /forgot_password/:unique_key
     class: sfDoctrineRoute
     options: { model: sfGuardForgotPassword, type: object }
     param: { module: sfGuardForgotPassword, action: change }
     requirements:
       sf_method: [get, post]

   sf_guard_forgot_password:
     url:   /forgot_password
     param: { module: sfGuardForgotPassword, action: index }
   ```
3. **enable the mailing** in `factories.yml` (beware of [differences for prod/dev env.](http://www.metulo.net/how-to-send-an-email-with-symfony-and-gmail). [See also the official doc.](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/16)):

   ```
   all:
     mailer:
       class: sfMailer
       param:
       logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
       charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
       delivery_strategy: realtime
       transport:
         class: Swift_SmtpTransport
         param:
           host:       smtp.example.com
           port:       25
           encryption: ~
           username:   test@example.com
           password:   p4ssw0rd
   ```
4. **add senders address** to `app.yml` (and routing which doesn't work automatic for me). Address in app.yml and factories.yml should be same, otherwise the smtp-server might complain:

   ```
    all:
     sf_guard_plugin:
       routes_register: true
       default_from_email: test@example.com
   ```
5. Touch the `apps/your_app/modules/sfGuardForgotPassword/config/security.yml` to [**make the request form accessible while logged out**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085192/620410):

   ```
   secure:
     is_secure: true      
   index:
     is_secure: false       
   change:
     is_secure: false
   ```
6. **clear the cache** with `./symfony cc`.

Now forget your password.

Comment: Only thing, instead of `apps/your_app/sfGuardForgotPassword/config/security.yml`, it should read `apps/your_app/modules/sfGuardForgotPassword/config/security.yml`

Answer (score 0):

If I recall reading right, the sfDoctrineGuard doesn't have a "getPassword" method that would do what it needs to... retrieve the password unencrypted.

I'm using DuoSRX's first recommendation: creating a new password, saving it with $user->setPassword (which handles salting & hashing automatically), and emailing it to the user. The user is then advised to login and create a new password.