# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin Documentation

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I am trying to customize sfDoctrineGuardPlugin to fit into my model and tie things together.  Problem is I don't see very thorough documentation beyond how to set it up.  I could go through and read the code, but it would be nice if there was a reference manual of some sort.  Is there such a thing that I just can't find?

My main goal is to use emails for logins, tie in a user id to the rest of my model, etc, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineApplyPlugin. Yo can see there how they associate the id of the sf_guard_user with the sf_guard_user_profile table.
Otherwise you can check in /plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/validator/sfGuardValidatorUser.class.php how validates the user and pass

Comment: Better check sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin, which is a fork of former, but has evolved very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the readme section here ?

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

It was the only doc I have found when I have installed doctrineGuard in my app

Answer (score 0):

There's an extended documentation on the origin sfGuardPlugin which is also suitable for sfDoctrineGuardPlugin :

- http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfGuardPluginExtraDocumentation

Answer (score 0):

I added [installation instructions for the forgot password feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944082/620410) on this site.