# sfDoctrineGuard and Forgot Password function

Tags: php, symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I'm pretty new to smyfony and I've been playing around with that sfDoctrineGuard plugin the whole day.
it's working for the most part. I'm just having troubles with the forgot_password function.

Actually I did everything according to the readme file in the plugin.

the problem is:

in security.yml i set

default:
  is_secure:true

obviously in the module sfGuard there's a security.yml that sais:

secure:
  is_secure: false

signin:
  is_secure: false

signout:
  is_secure: false

which makes sense, cause otherwise the login site wouldn't be accessible.

BUT

it doesn't seem to work with the forgot_password function:

routing.yml

sf_guard_signin:
  url:   /login
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin }

sf_guard_signout:
  url:   /logout
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_forgot_password:
  url:   /forgot_password
  param: { module: sfGuardForgotPassword, action: index }

sf_guard_forgot_password_change:
  url:   /forgot_password/:unique_key
  class: sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: sfGuardForgotPassword, type: object }
  param: { module: sfGuardForgotPassword, action: change }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get, post]

i cannot access /forgot_password as I am rerouted to the /login page.
so i put a security.yml with

forgot_password:
  is_secure: false

in the config directory of the sfGuardForgotPassword module.
But that doesn't seem to be working.

and it's not working if i put this in the global security.yml either :-(

Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 2):

In `/app/modules/sfGuardForgotPassword/config/security.yml` I have:

```
secure:
  is_secure: true

index:
  is_secure: false

change:
  is_secure: false
```

In that app's routing.yml file I have:

```
sf_guard_signin:
  url:   /login
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin }

sf_guard_signout:
  url:   /logout
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_forgot_password:
  url:   /forgot_password
  param: { module: sfGuardForgotPassword, action: index }

sf_guard_forgot_password_change:
  url:   /forgot_password/:unique_key
  class: sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: sfGuardForgotPassword, type: object }
  param: { module: sfGuardForgotPassword, action: change }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get, post]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin](https://github.com/fizyk/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin) for this. Working good :)

Answer (score 0):

The forgot password feature was missing from the plugin. I wrote some changes to the code to add in the feature. I changed the password to reversible encryption so users can have their passwords emailed. Let me know if anyone wants to see code. We could fork a git repo and work on it together. It works.